# ffmpeg cropped video changes aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect

I have a heterogenous set of videos (codecs, dimensions, size) that I would like to crop off the top using ffmpeg.  I've used this code successfully for year without any trouble (example here crops off 64px):

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -qscale 1 -vcodec libx264 -vf crop=in_w:in_h-64:0:64 out.mp4
```

However, I've now run into a case that it does *not* work correctly, and I suspect it has something to do with SAR and DAR.  I have a clip that shows pixel dimensions of 960x720 [SAR 960:720 DAR 16:9], original looks close to this:

[image: original]

When I use the above command, I end up with a video that ffprobe/ffmpeg says is 960x656 [SAR 4:3 DAR 80:41], but when I view it on a web browser or quicktime it is displayed as 1280x656:

[image: output]

How can I modify the command to account for this use case, without breaking the cropping of all other clips?  Here's what I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -qscale 1 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=960:656,setsar=1 -vf crop=in_w:in_h-64:0:64 out.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.avi -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -qscale 1 -vcodec libx264 -vf setsar=sar=0 -vf setdar=dar=0 -vf crop=in_w:in_h-64:0:64 out.mp4
```

Comment: Here's an archive of the input and output files I'm getting. https://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/give/uploads/clips.zip

Comment: "Keep in mind that the sample aspect ratio set by the setsar filter may be changed by later filters in the filterchain, e.g. if another "setsar" or a "setdar" filter is applied." - so the correct order is needed and as said by @orgoro possibly try to do not separate filters and instead do: -vf "filter1=...,filter2=...,filter3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work universally.

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -qscale 1 -vcodec libx264 -vf setsar=1,crop=in_w:in_h-64:0:64 out.mp4
```

Comment: @user255406 libx264 ignores `-qscale`. [Use `-crf` instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: It looks like in some cases you can simply use `setsar=` or even just `setsar`

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg accepts only **one** video filter (marked as -vf)
you should merge all the video filters you want into one, comma separated string:

`ffmpeg ... -vf setsar=1,crop=in_w:in_h-64:0:64 out.mp4`